# "Illegally post-declared types" with circular class definition

Tags: porting, raku

Rakudo version 2020.01

This does not compile.

```
use v6;

class N1 {}
class T1 {}

class G1 {
    has @.g is required where A1|Q1;
}

class Q1 {
    has $.q is required where N1|T1|G1;
}

class A1 {
    has Q1 @.a is required;
}
```

---

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling …
Illegally post-declared types:
    A1 used at line 7
    Q1 used at line 7
```

I thought that declaring just the identifiers ahead of G1 would help me, but this also fails:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling …
Too late for unit-scoped class definition;
Please use the block form.
…:6
------> class A1;⏏ class Q1;
```

---

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, but you need to define the classes as a stub.

```
class A { }
```

will just define an empty class.  Whereas:

```
class A { ... }   # note the yadayadayada
```

will define a stub.  So adding:

```
class A1 { ... }
class Q1 { ... }
```

to the top of your code, should fix the problem.